# I'm a bit confused about votes

Tags: discussion, support

I know y'all are going to downvote this post just like that guy 2 posts below this one... idc because this is meta, but... just whatever.

I've been asking lots of questions in the past, and I.. I don't know.  I think they're OK, but I keep getting 3 downvotes on all of 'em.  Yes, 3.  Anyway, I just wanna know WHY?  I mean, it's not like I'm asking bogus questions or my grammar sucks.  And apparently, I got like thousands of views for a dumb question like [Double blue lines in Word](https://superuser.com/questions/1157307/double-blue-lines-in-word).  Yes, that's how I got 63 rep.  So what's going on here?  Am I just like really bad or what?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1187755/internet-speed-is-sinking-for-downloading-lol One Bad bros vague question with 3 downvotes?

Comment: There are others @Ramhound

Comment: I deleted them, so my reputation won't down.

Comment: And what do you mean vague?  I seriously don't see why that's vague.

Comment: All of them? You have 6 questions on SU. Only one of them has any downvotes. And that one is a bad question. It is just a complaint with no information at all that will help anybody to resolve your issue.

Comment: @Daneolog Deleted questions still count your ability to ask new questions.  The one question that has downvotes is a bad question, it's not answerable, in its current form

Comment: @Daneolog Deleting your "bad" questions won't stop you from being question banned. And if you delete them we cannot advise you on how to improve them.

Comment: @DavidPostill What kind of information do I have to put?  I already put all I know (the KBps information on LoL)!

Comment: Well OK.  I'm talking about this question that you're talking about.

Comment: And I have another question.  Why was THIS question downvoted?  Hmm?  Too vague?  Not enough information?  Cannot ask about problems?  What?

Comment: @DavidPostill and by the way, I do want to keep reputation.  Would I rather both lose reputation AND get question banned or only get question banned?

Comment: That's why I kept this question on.  So I can ask you guys.

Comment: "it's not like I'm asking bogus questions or my grammar sucks" Your grammar in this question "sucks". 1/ Use of slang words 2/ Use of text speak. 3/ ...

Comment: Slang words?  Like conjunctions?

Comment: Every SINGLE question about BootCamp that I have asked in the past... 2 weeks have been downvoted at least 3 times before I deleted them.  If I didn't delete any of them I'd probably be at around 30.  So yeah, I suppose I'm a bit ticked off.

Comment: @DavidPostill I just asked this post to get help, not to vent my anger (although I could).  So could you PLEASE stop subtly insulting me and help me out?  Because (don't take offense to this) I feel that Stack Exchange is full of people who are trigger-happy and love downvoting.

Comment: Your getting downvotes to this question because your complaining and your not willing to accept feedback.  You think there is nothing wrong with your questions and the problem must be the community is doing.  something wrong.  It seems to me your asking what's wrong with that question but when we tell you it's vague your not willing to accept that feedback

Comment: "Internet speeds is sinking" is grammatically confusing.  " I forgot what it was when I was on the mac.." isn't helpful, it doesn't tell us anything, avoid telling us what you don't know.  Because my first thought is to ask you to go find out what the speed was.  You told us nothing about your internet connection nor your intranet network, nor anything about the network  hardware your using.  Your also didn't provide us measurements from say speedtest nor what kind of speeds your actually expecting.

Comment: @Daneolog Nobdy has "subtly" insulted you, don't take the feedback you asked us for, personally.

Answer (score 9):

I took a look at the downvoted questions and well, I can't blame [Tim Post's keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/135565) this time.

[This one](https://superuser.com/questions/1187755/internet-speed-is-sinking-for-downloading-lol) is unclear about what you're asking. How does one "download a partition" and download speeds may be dependant on the other side too.

[This one](https://superuser.com/questions/1178747/does-a-vmware-virtual-machine-take-up-memory-when-off) is a bit of a mess too. Asking questions as a stream of consciousness does that. I suppose it is also semi-trivial to test.

[This one is too broad](https://superuser.com/q/1178813/10165) - especially when we don't know how the VM is set up or what you're doing with it.

[This one](https://superuser.com/questions/1185047/my-boot-camp-partition-doesnt-want-to-boot-after-resizing-through-disk-utility)... lacks any information that's useful in solving your problem.

[This one](https://superuser.com/questions/1185059/how-long-on-average-does-it-take-to-partition-a-disk-using-boot-camp) is like asking how long a piece of string is - it depends on partion size, the tool used, the drive speed, plausibly the phase of the moon...

While the question you asked is "why?" the answer you need is "what do I do"

We have a template for mod messaging folks for poor quality questions - I'm reproducing it in part here for your benefit

> Specifically, many of your questions were downvoted and closed because they seemed to be hastily written, or of the [type that we'd prefer users refrain from asking](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). This is a troubling pattern; we'd like to make sure that you've read the help that we have available for asking questions. Please take some time to read *all* of the information linked below prior to asking another question:
>
> - An overview of [how our system works](https://superuser.com/tour)
> - A brief [guide on how to ask questions](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)
> - A short summary of [questions we permit](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)
> - Help on [formatting your questions](https://superuser.com/editing-help)

Less text speak, and more time formulating your questions would be nice. Ask yourself "If someone called me up and offered me money if I fixed their computer, what would I ask them?" and include these things in your question.

So, yeah, that's why you got downvoted.